# W3 Validator cant Check

Tags: wordpress, validation, xml-rpc, w3c-validation

my XML-RPC Protocol on Wordpress doesnt work!
Thats why i wanted to use the W3 Validator. I just typed my URL and clicked OK.

The validation results where:

> I got the following unexpected response when trying to retrieve http://subtarget.net:
>   500 Internal Server Error

Thats weird because PC's can access my Website without any problems

my site name is: www.subtarget.net

Thank you.

**EDIT: I removed the .htaccess and tried again, but still ive got the 500 Error code ..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is somewhere in your encoding. If you set the validator's encoding to iso-8859-1 at options, then it will do the validation:
[http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsubtarget.net%2F&charset=iso-8859-1&doctype=Inline&group=0&No200=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://subtarget.net/&charset=iso-8859-1&doctype=Inline&group=0&No200=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services)